# VisualForce : Error CPU time limit exceeded in scheuled job

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex, cpulimit, asyncapexjob

I have a scheduled job that sends page content via email,
page controller needs about 15 sec to finish executing(looping over histories of more than one object) so sometimes scheduled job fails because of the limit.
Is there a way to make page.getcontent().tostring() takes the 60 sec specified for scheduled job not 15 sec.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't run Visualforce with the higher asynchronous limit. You'll just have to render your content in the scheduled class directly, or build multiple pages that can run, and you can then combine them together afterwards.